# Getting incompatible types in assignment

Tags: c

These are two structures, client & employee

```
struct client
{
    char clID[10];
    char cname[50];
    char caddress[99];
    char cemail[99];
    char cfees[6];
    char ceID[10];
    char cename[50];
}typedef client;

struct employee
{
    char empID[10];
    char ename[50];
    double erate;
    double ehours;
    double esalary;
    int clientCount;
}typedef employee;
```

This is a search case in which after entering information for a client the user is prompted to assign an employee by ID and then the employee name stored in that ID is added to cename in the client struct

```
case 1: getClient(clCount, pcli);
                        printf("Enter an employee to assign to this client: ");
                        scanf("%9s", searchID);
                        searchEmp(searchID, pemp, empCount);
                        foundAt = searchEmp(searchID, pemp, empCount);
                        if(foundAt >= 0)
                            if(pemp[foundAt].clientCount < 5)
                            {
                                strcpy(pcli[clCount].ceID, searchID);
```

This line is where the error is coming from
pcli[clCount].cename = pemp[foundAt].ename;

```
                                pcli[clCount].cename = pemp[foundAt].ename;
                                pemp[foundAt].clientCount++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                printf("Max clients reached for this employee!");
                            }
                        else
                            printf("%s is not found anywhere\n", searchID);
                        clCount++;
                    break;
```

Search method:

```
int searchEmp(char* searchID, employee* pemp, int empCount)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < empCount; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(searchID,(pemp + i)->empID)==0)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}//end searchClient
```

Comment: Try ironing out the symtax errs - e.g. `struct ... typedef client`

Comment: Do you want to copy the string? In that case, why not strncpy?

Comment: Yeah, I need the string located in pemp[foundAt].ename to be copied to pcli[clCount].cename

Comment: @EdHeal: just edit that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(pcli[clCount].cename, pemp[foundAt].ename);
```

or `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(pcli[clCount].cename, pemp[foundAt].ename, sizeof(pcli[clCount].cename)-1);
pcli[clCount].cename[sizeof(pcli[clCount].cename)-1] = '\0';
```

Literal assignment does not work in C as it does with strings in C++. They do not get copied automatically. Their addresses will get copied, but here you are even using static buffers...

Comment: `sizeof(pemp[foundAt])` is not the right size to use; and also you need to think about null termination.